# Why is the average number of suspects three or more in Detective Conan?

Tags: detective-conan

I'm curious as to why in almost every Detective Conan case there are always around three suspects? Even when there are cases with many suspects, Conan always narrows it down to three or four suspects. When there is a case involving a serial killer there are at least three suspects at the end.

Is there any explanation from Aoyama Gosho about this?

Comment: Having only 1 suspect would either make Conan look dumb if he's wrong, or take away the suspense if he's right. Having 2 suspects would also take away the suspense, because it's obvious that the most suspicious guy is actually innocent. With 3 or 4 suspects, we have a good balance, and the culprit is no longer as easy to identify. More than 4 suspects would either make Conan look dumb, or it would require considerable effort to make them all believable.

Comment: @Nolonar That sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

Three is a number that would make the story go more smoothly. If there were only 2 suspects, the evidence would continuously weigh one one another, making the case go for 5 chapters compared to the usual three. If there are four, or more than such, it would be like watching longer replays of the 50 million suspects case, but these are fillers with no specific information that is important to the timeline, so they should not go longer than 3 chapters.

Comment: Having always three suspects is dumb too. There were one chapter where they narrowed the suspects to three even though the suspects were the persons that were hospitalized during 3 days in a big hospital. That doesn't make any sense. There are other detective series where the culprit is always known at the start and the story go smoothly. It is just the author/editor found something that works and don't want to change. In DC, things rarely change, movies have the same story lines (Detective Boys are present for some reason, Shinishi appears to save Ran who is in near death situation, ...etc.).